# Creating mixin with Spring AOP Introductions

Tags: spring, aop, mixins

Could someone provide a sample code snippet that stitches two java interfaces using spring-aop introduction (mixin)?

I'm looking for AspectJ annotation style configuration. Also, the specific use case I have is to stitch a few java beans each implementing their own interfaces together. So, rather than having a delegate coded, if I could just get away by using Spring XML, it'd be awesome.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `@DeclareParents` or `<aop:declare-parents>` to get the mixin behavior. For example,

```
@DeclareParents(value="service.*", defaultImpl=AuditRecorderDefaultImpl.class)
private AuditRecorder mixin;
```

will mixin all classes in the `service` package with the `AuditRecorder` interface automatically forwarding each method to `AuditRecorderDefaultImpl`.

You can see working examples of this from AspectJ in Action's [downloadable sources](http://manning.com/laddad2). You can also see detailed explanation in [Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/aop.html#aop-introductions).

Answer (score 1):

A demo based on Spring in Action book 4th edition is [here](https://github.com/peckwood/sia_p115_4.3.4_introduction/), the configuration is JavaConfig style with @ComponentScan

Comment: I could not understand how the introduced methods are called. The Spring in Action 4 book is not clear about it. This example helped, thank you.